# VueJS y node para un paso a produccion

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, router

Tengo una duda, tengo un proyecto hechoc con `vue-cli`, corro el comando `npm run build`, genero el `dist` y el `index`.

La idea es desplegar en un nodejs, el cual me provee servicios y conexion a la BD (mongo) le accedo y hago peticiones para consumir servicios y eso;  cuando copio y pego las carpetas en la `public` de nodejs puedo acceder correctamente pero al momento de hace una recarga de la pagina obtengo

```
CANNOT GET /DIRECCION
```

¿Cómo se solucionaría eso?

Comment: Se soluciono, era algo del servidor node, se habilito que siempre apuntara al index.html y el vue-router se activo el historico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"CANNOT GET /DIRECCION". No encuentra /direccion. Es correcta esa ruta?. Me ha pasado, a veces, que me equivoco con una letra. Pruebe con Postman.

Comment: esto no provee una respuesta, pues no da claridad al OP sobre el error, por favor las respuestas deben ser claras completas y de ayuda

Comment: Estoy escribiendo que puede ser un error en el path. A mi me pasa frecuentemente. Postman es una herramienta de depuración que en la mayoría de los casos ayuda a encontrar los errores. A veces lo que uno necesita es una pequeña ayuda para seguir en el proyecto. Por mi puntaje no puedo comentar sobre la pregunta así que decidí ofrecer mi colaboración.